# Why is `multiprocessing.Process.start` acting this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a list:

```
mylist = list(range(10))
```

and a function:

```
def change():
    for i, _ in enumerate(mylist):
       mylist[i] = 0
```

when I execute the code below:

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=change).start()
print(mylist)
print(multiprocessing.active_children())
```

the output is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[]
```

So, the process ends but it does not change the elements of the list, `mylist`.

But when I execute the exact code with threads:

```
threading.Thread(target=change).start()
```

it does change the list. But in my context I specifically need to use processes instead of threads.

Furthermore, if I call `multiprocessing.Process.run` instead of `multiprocessing.Process.start`, it also "works" but it is blocking. Why does it work like this?

Comment: not long enough for an answer... separate processes have separate memory, the child process changed it's local copy of the list, and then the process exited, and all those changes were never communicated to the parent process. you need to do some research on inter-process communication

Comment: the two biggest things that separate threads and processes in python is that threads share memory while processes don't, and threads are restricted by the global interpreter lock, while processes are not.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I am quite unfamiliar with processes, but I get it, I think. Can you explain how a process differs from a thread so that the output I specified varies?

Comment: Oh, never mind, you answered before I asked; thank you!

Comment: You need to debug, https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: [Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Without going too deep under the hood of how the stuff works, stuff you pass to the `args` keyword of the `Process` constructor will be sent to the child. if one of those is something like a pipe or a queue, the child can use that to send results back.

Comment: Special objects like `multiprocessing.shared_memory` or managed proxy objects `multiprocessing.Manager` "automatically" send changes from the child to the parent.